# Can't decline a flag without the mouse

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, accessibility

While this is a fairly rare edge case, I found myself in a position where I was unable to decline a flag while not being able to use a mouse.

Trying to <kbd>tab</kbd> to the "decline" button skips right over it. The decline button should be able to be selected via tab, and then a reason chosen using the arrow keys or number keys, like other similar menus around the network.

<sub>If you're confused as to why it's important that things be accessible without the mouse, please read up on [keyboard accessibility](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/). While I thankfully don't have any physical problems with using 
a mouse, I'm using my time with a broken mouse to give accessibility feedback so that people who need it can get a better site experience.</sub>